# Intellij or Clion formatter to merge short lines

Tags: intellij-idea, formatting, clion

My IntelliJ and Clion can help split a long line into multiple with the auto-formatting, but the not the other way around. How should it merge multiple short lines into a single longer line?

This is needed quite often. For example it happens after I renaming a long variable, and that makes the function call chain being able to fit in a single line.

Example, what I want is:

1. Codes before formatting:

```java
anObject
.aMethod()
.aField()
```

2. Intellij or Clion auto-format should change it to:

```java
anObject.aMethod().aField()
```

Comment: Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Code Style | Java | Wrapping and Braces | Keep when reformatting | Line breaks -> disable: https://i.imgur.com/tgDc3RZ.png.

Comment: FYI, I removed your `netbeans` tag since it seems to be completely irrelevant for your question.